# python to cython - eliminate python calls

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I'm currently trying to convert the following loops to cython:

```
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn of bounds-checking for entire function
def Interpolation(cells, int nmbcellsx):
    cdef np.ndarray[float, ndim=1] x,y,z
    cdef int i,j,len
    for i in range(nmbcellsx):
      x = cells[i].x
      y = cells[i].y
      z = cells[i].z
      len = x.size
      for j in range(len):
         x[j] = x[j] * y[j] * z[j]

    return 0
```

So far everything looks kind of okay, but the accesses to cells[i].* still require python calls. This prevents parallelization of the i-loop.

Here is a cython feedback (generated with cython -a):

[cython -a feedback](http://i49.tinypic.com/30sarye.png)

Hence the question: How can I remove these python callbacks (i.e. such that line 9-12 become white)?

When I try to add the type of the Cell like this:

```
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

cdef class cell_t:
   cdef np.ndarray x,y,z

@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn of bounds-checking for entire function
def Interpolation(np.ndarray[cell_t,ndim=1] cells, int nmbcellsx):
    cdef np.ndarray[float, ndim=1] x,y,z
    cdef int i,j,len
    for i in range(nmbcellsx):
      x = cells[i].x
      y = cells[i].y
      z = cells[i].z
      len = x.size
      for j in range(len):
         x[j] = x[j] * y[j] * z[j]

    return 0
```

I receive the following cython error: dtype must be "object", numeric type or a struct (it is complaining about the cell_t within the declaration)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Of what type is the `cells` argument. If you give Cython the hint for it you might be able to make it recognize it.

Comment: Also as a side-note. You seem to be not returning anything at all from the function related to the loop, nor does the loop mutate anything not-local. Just a heads-up.

Comment: This is just a simplyfied example of a more complicated function. cells is actually a numpy ndarray of objects of calls Cell. Let's just say the Cell class has only the numpy arrays x,y and z. How can I resolve this?

Comment: After some [research](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.cython.user/565), I can't seem to find any method of having a type that contains 3 other `numpy.ndarray`'s and this nested structure seems to be not supported yet. Even 3 years later.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't telling **Cython** the type of your `cells` argument and thus it will use the **Python** look up methods. Try changing the definition to the following:

`def Interpolation(np.ndarray cells, int nmbcellsx):`

This will tell **Cython** it is getting the `ndarray` type and thus can use **C** accessing.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not change anything. My guess is that I've to tell cython about the exact composition of the Cell but how do I do that? Btw. you can compile the above example with "cython -a file.py" and then look at the generated file.html (line 9-12 need to become (pale) white)

Answer (score 2):

How about using [Typed Memoryview](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html)?

```
cimport cython

cdef class cell_t:
    cdef public float[:] x, y, z

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z


@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn of bounds-checking for entire function
def Interpolation(cell_t[:] cells, int nmbcellsx):
    cdef float[:] x,y,z
    cdef int i,j,length
    cdef cell_t cell
    for i in range(nmbcellsx):
        cell = cells[i]
        x = cell.x
        y = cell.y
        z = cell.z
        length = len(x)
        for j in range(length):
            x[j] = x[j] * y[j] * z[j]
    return 0
```

Here is the test code:

```
import numpy as np
from cells import cell_t, Interpolation

x = np.array([1,2,3], np.float32)
y = np.array([4,5,6], np.float32)
z = np.array([7,8,9], np.float32)
c1 = cell_t(x, y, z)

x = np.array([1,1,1,1,1], np.float32)
y = np.array([2,2,2,2,2], np.float32)
z = np.array([3,3,3,3,3], np.float32)
c2 = cell_t(x, y, z)

cells = np.array([c1, c2], object)

Interpolation(cells, 2)

print c1.x.base
print c2.x.base
```

and the output:

```
[  28.   80.  162.]
[ 6.  6.  6.  6.  6.]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very close to the actual solution but there is still one minor obstacle to prallelization. Cython seems to add some checks wheter the x,y and z arrays are NOT NULL (see [here](http://i48.tinypic.com/jqgyhk.png)). Looking at [this page](http://wiki.cython.org/enhancements/compilerdirectives) I can't find an option to turn this check off. Do you know if this is possible? On a side-note, the goal is to uncomment line 21.